# Can't implement Iterator design pattern after JsonConvert when trying to Deserialize json

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, json.net

I have the following Object that matches the pattern of a JSON object i get from one REST request I send:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public List<string> columns { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> rows { get; set; }
        public DisplayValue displayValue { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public object alert { get; set; }
    }

    public class DisplayValue
    {
        public Id DisplayId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Id
    {
        public List<string> IdToName { get; set; }
    }
```

this object match to the response I get and the next code is working with the upper implementation of MyObject (I'm using C#'s RestSharp):

```
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response.Content);
```

Now I would like to implement the Iterator design pattern on MyObject since MyObject.rows is the only field I actually use.

So I've changed **MyObject** class to the following

```
public class MyObject : IEnumerable<List<string>
    {
        public List<string> columns { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> rows { get; set; }
        public DisplayValue displayValue { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public object alert { get; set; }
    }


        public IEnumerator<List<string>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (List<string> row in rows)
            {
                yield return row;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class DisplayValue
    {
        public Id DisplayId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Id
    {
        public List<string> IdToName { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I try to JSONConvert I get the following exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'MyObject' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.

Any idea to why is this happening?

Comment: Show the value of `response.Content` (the actual `string` you're passing for deserialization).

Comment: Exception message give some information: _or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, **not a collection type like an array or List**)_. By implementing `IEnumerable` in your type you made your type a collection

Comment: @Fabio thanks for that, so if I understand correctly, if I want my object to implement IEnumerable I would first have to parse the json to a non-collection type and then initialize my IEnumerable with that object. Am I right?

Comment: Why you want implement `IEnumerable`? Why you cannot use `MyObject.rows` straight?

Comment: @Fabio Readability, but if it can't be implemented simply, and it looks like its not possible, i'm just going to use MyObject.rows

Comment: I think if you show us your original json string, you will get maybe some another ideas to support readability in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Json.NET will try to serialize any POCO that implements `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T` as a JSON *array* rather than a JSON *object*, as is documented [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Lists).  Since your JSON is presumably not an array, you receive the exception you are seeing.

Since you don't want your `MyObject` serialized as an array, you can force Json.NET to (de)serialize it as an object instead by marking it with [`[JsonObject]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm):

```
[JsonObject]
public class MyObject : IEnumerable<List<string>>
{
    public List<string> columns { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> rows { get; set; }
    public DisplayValue displayValue { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public object alert { get; set; }

    // Implementation of IEnumerable<List<string>>...
}
```

See [JsonObjectAttribute force object serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOverrideIEnumerable.htm).